# C# Console writeline breaks string and does wrong output

Tags: c#, string, console, formatting

I just have a basic class CNode with Name string property.I just wanted to write it in console,and everything was fine.But when i used + in string,it broked output.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(node.name);
```

Gived output: `word0`
Also:

```cs
string name = node.Name;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Too gived output: `word0`
But:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(node.Name + ":");
```

Gived output: `:ord0`

Whats wrong?
Also i tried:

```
string name = node.Name + ":";
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

and is too gives me: `:ord0`

**NOTE:**

```cs
string name = ":"+node.Name;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

gives me `:word0` output

If it will be helpful,node object class code:

```cs
public class CNode
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Please help,i expected to get `word0:` output

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? At the moment, we don't know where `word0` comes from. Are you sure it is the 5 characters w, o , r, d and 0? Are you sure there aren't any hidden characters in there? You can check this by printing `node.Name.Length`.

Comment: hm lenght is 7.

Comment: This would be the behavior if Name is terminated with a carriage return (\r) which is not visible but returns the cursor to beginning of the line.

Comment: Hm.i writed: `node.Name = node.Name.Replace("\r","");` and is fixed

Comment: See? Now loop through each character of the string and print out its int value by casting it to `int`, so we know exactly which characters they are. Do something like: `foreach(char c in node.Name) {Console.WriteLine((int)c);}`

Comment: @Sweeper it gave me all the chars and whitespace after it

Comment: i dont know why here is a `\r` in string,because i set a node.Name from another class string property which is `word0`

Answer (score 1):

The string that i tired to write is had `"\r"`,so if i need a normal output,i just need to do `node.Name = node.Name.Replace("\r","");`

Answer (score -1):

Try this, maybe it will help you:

```
string name = node.Name
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} :", name));
```